# For which $\alpha$ does this integral converge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^{\alpha}} dx$$
I'm stuck on this, I'm supposed to solve it from $0$ to $\infty$, from the $(1,\infty)$ case i got $\alpha>2$. Here I’m supposed to show that $\alpha < 4$ and I don’t understand why...

EDIT: How stupid I am, thanks a lot!:)
Solved

Comment: I don't know how rigorous your proof needs to be, but probably the simplest way to see this is by Taylor expanding the sine.

Comment: By the way, I tried limit comparison test with x^a and from there I believe it follows that a <1. Could you please clarify where I am wrong?:)

Comment: I guess you didn't take into account the numerator, which  is $O(x^3)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a positive function, so you may use *equivalents*:
$$x-\sin x\sim_0\frac{x^3}6,\quad\text{so }\quad \frac{x-\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}\sim_0\frac{x^3}{6x^\alpha}=\frac1{6x^{\alpha-3}}, $$
which converges if and only if $\;\alpha-3<1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you please answer my question in the comment above?:)