# For which $\alpha$, integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\arctan{x}-x}{x^\alpha}dx$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I have to find for which $\alpha$ values this integral converges:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\arctan{x}-x}{x^\alpha}dx$$

My first approach was to separate the two components in $\frac{\arctan{x}}{x^\alpha}$ and $\frac{x}{x^\alpha}$ but after seeing this [For which $\alpha$ does this integral converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753026/for-which-alpha-does-this-integral-converge) I tried seeing it under another point of view, $\arctan{x}$ can be rewritten (using Taylor) as $x-\frac{x^3}3$. This would make the integral:

$$-\frac13\int_0^{+\infty}\frac1{x^{\alpha-2}} = -\frac13\frac1{(\alpha-1)x^{\alpha-1}}\bigg|_0^t$$
with $t\in [0,+\infty)$. Then

$$-\frac13\frac1{(\alpha-1)0^{\alpha-1}}+\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}-\frac13\frac1{(\alpha-1)t^{\alpha-1}}$$

While the second term can clearly converge for $\alpha\geq 1$ where it would converge to $0$, the first term confuses me a bit. How do I go on from here? Did I get something wrong?

Comment: A very precise upper bound that you can use is $\arctan x<\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{1+x}$ for $x\in[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is coming from your Taylor expansion. When $x\to\infty$, $\arctan(x)\to\frac\pi2$ which is bounded, but your Taylor expansion $x-\frac13x^3\to-\infty$. Hence, you need to discuss them separately. For example,

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\arctan{x}-x}{x^\alpha}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan{x}-x}{x^\alpha}dx+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\arctan{x}-x}{x^\alpha}dx$$

For $\int_0^1\frac{\arctan{x}-x}{x^\alpha}dx$, you can use Taylor expansion, and discuss the convergence/divergence around $x=0$.

$$\int_0^\epsilon\frac{\arctan{x}-x}{x^\alpha}dx\approx -\frac13\int_0^\epsilon\frac{x^3}{x^\alpha}dx\Longrightarrow \alpha<4$$

For $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\arctan{x}-x}{x^\alpha}dx$, you use the fact that $\arctan(x)$ is bounded by $\frac\pi2$, and discuss the convergence/divergence when $x\to\infty$.

$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\arctan{x}-x}{x^\alpha}dx= \int_1^{\infty}\frac{\arctan{x}}{x^\alpha}dx- \int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\alpha-1}}dx$$

The second term gives $\alpha>2$. Next, for the first term, we have

$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\arctan{x}}{x^\alpha}dx\le \frac\pi2\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^\alpha}dx\Longrightarrow \alpha>1$$

hence, the integral converges when

$$2<\alpha<4$$

Comment: Thanks so I'll get working on the first part, but I'm kinda stuck solving the integral without Taylor expansion. When you say "you use the fact that arctan() is bounded by /2" what do you mean, how can I use it to my advantage?

Comment: Your OP said to find the range of $\alpha$ such that this integral converges. Now you said to solve this integral. If you want to solve it and get a closed form, you will have more work to do.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to diverge from my original post. I just then missed how can we find the range of $\alpha$ without the closed form

Comment: I put more details.